# ag Grid ability to pre-select a checkbox based on the data

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, angular10

### As per the requirement we will get values from api and those rows should be pre-selected when loading Ag Grid.

---

```
this.columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: 'Option Code',
        field: 'Option',
        maxWidth: 125,
        checkboxSelection: true,
      }
];

this.addOption = ["000005","000010","000026"]; // External data
```

On Grid Ready:

```
onGridReady(params) { 
    this.gridApi = params.api; 
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi; 
    this.gridApi.getRenderedNodes().forEach(function (node:any) {
        node.setSelected(this.addOption.includes(
            node.data.Option.toString()
        )); 
     }); 
}
```

We are trying below code to pre-select default checkbox and it is not working.

```
selectAllAmerican(val) { 
    this.gridApi.getRenderedNodes().forEach(function (node:any) {
        node.setSelected(val.includes(node.data.Option.toString()));
    }); 
}
```

The above code is working when we used under Get button. Kindly review and guide us.

Comment: On Grid Ready:
onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    this.gridApi.getRenderedNodes().forEach(function (node:any) {     
            node.setSelected(this.addOption.includes(node.data.Option.toString()));

        });
  }

Comment: We are trying below code to pre-select default checkbox and it is not working.

  selectAllAmerican(val) {
   this.gridApi.getRenderedNodes().forEach(function (node:any) { 
        node.setSelected(val.includes(node.data.Option.toString()));

    });
  }

The above code is working when we used under Get button.

Kindly review and guide us .

Comment: Hi there, could you put all the code and explanation into the question, rather than adding it as comments. That means everything is in the same place, in the question.

Comment: Added comments into question body

Comment: As per the requirement we will get values from api and those rows should be pre-selected when loading Ag Grid and when user select/Un Select the check box need to perform the task

Answer (score 2):

Answering late , I faced a similar problem , and the solution is to put the below line when the rowData or grid data is ready be it and also in GridReady method.
so mention this in both places .

```
this.gridApi?.forEachNode(function (node) {
                        node.setSelected(true);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the requirement we will get values from api and those rows should be pre-selected when loading Ag Grid and when user select/Un Select the check box need to perform the task.
Column defination   this.columnDefs = [
{
headerName: 'Option Code',
field: 'Option',
maxWidth: 125,
checkboxSelection: true,
}
];

Grid Defination :

```
  <ag-grid-angular
  #agGrid
  style="width: 375px; height: 100%; display: inline-block;"
  *ngIf="Flag12"
  id="myGrid"
  class="userclass"
  [enableBrowserTooltips]="true"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
  [suppressRowClickSelection]="true"
  [rowSelection]="rowSelection"
  [rowDeselection]="true"
  [rowData]="rowData"
```

(rowSelected)="onRowSelected($event)"

```
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  >
```

this.addOption = ["000005","000010","000026"]; // External data

Two Questions :
1.How to pre-select checkbox based on external variable this.addOption .
2. rowSelected : In case of pr-select(when we are enabling the checkbox from logic), rowSelected should disable and when user select/un Select checkbox rowSelected  (need to perform some logic ), due to logic it may enable other check box from back-end. So it should work when user select and un select .

Kindly guide me .

Comment: Ag-grid not support all the the feature and I am not using ag-grid , since it is very difficult to implement all the option . It is working simple  scenarios and I am not getting much support from  forum .